# New folder 'androidlav' in gallery

Tags: gallery

I use Samsung Galaxy Note 5. I found a folder `androidlav` in the gallery section which has been formed automatically, and it contained a screenshot of MakeMyTrip app.

Does this happen to anyone? Can anybody explain this? Can I delete it?

Comment: You probably took a screenshot using internal app tool. You can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The folder is created by [AppVirality SDK](https://github.com/appvirality/appvirality-sdk-android).

Before [v1.1.18](https://github.com/appvirality/appvirality-sdk-android/wiki/Android-SDK-Version-History#version---1118), the folder is not hidden, and can be read by gallery apps.

> Version - 1.1.18
>
> Major Changes:
>
> Hidden androidlav folder from Android image gallery.

You can delete it. If it comes back, which it might if you open MakeMyTrip again, you should report it to them.