# What is 'androidlav' folder in Gallery?

Tags: gallery

I have Moto G2 running Android 5.0. From some time now in my Gallery app I see a folder named `androidlav`. This folder contains images from apps MakeMyTrip and Yatra. The images are of their offers. I am not sure what triggers the creation of these images. I was able to find another user with [similar problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/123959/30106); apparently in his case it takes screenshot of MakeMyTrip app, which is not the case with me.

What can be the reason for this? Is this something MakeMyTrip and Yatra apps are doing consciously? Do I face any security risks?

Comment: Related discussion on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Theres-a-folder-in-my-gallery-named-Android-lav-and-it-keeps-coming-back-every-time-I-delete-it-What-is-it-Do-I-have-to-be-worried): seems it's only used for the apps purpose, no harm done.

Comment: Also, the [linked question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123959/new-folder-androidlav-in-gallery) is a dupe: the reason is the same, and it's not a security risk, only a bug of the SDK.